# How to convert Django Queryset into a list in template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Here is my model :

```djangoclass
class Building(models.Model):
    Building_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    Building_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @property
    def BuildingFullName(self):
        fullname = '{} | {}'.format(self.Building_code, self.Building_name)
        return fullname

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Building_code
```

What i do in my template :

```django
<tbody>
{% for hira in hiras %}
    <tr>
         <td>{{ hira.Activity }}</td>
         <td>{{ hira.Hazard.Hazard }}</td>
         <td>{{ hira.PBS.Code }}</td>
         {% with allbuilding=hira.Building.all %}
             <td>{{ allbuilding }}</td>
         {% endwith %}
         <td>{{ hira.Building.Function_Mode }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

This is what I am getting :
[image: here]

But I would like the building list to be displayed without this "<Queryset". For the first row, it would be "13, 14".

Comment: You're going to need to show your view ...

Comment: Add your Building Model as well

Comment: Side note: you should read up on naming conventions for python, because you are not following them ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`join`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join):

```
{% with allbuilding=hira.Building.all %}
     <td>{{ allbuilding|join:", "  }}</td>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I was going to propse the same solution but let's see the Building model

Comment: Then upvote the answer as set as the acceptable answer so people can get back to it later